# VirtualBox - can't get shared folders to work with Oracle Linux 9.1 VB 7.0.4

Tags: virtualbox, oracle-linux

I never had a problem gettings shared folders to work before on lots of flavors. Switched to OracleLinux and boom - yeah can't get it to work. Guest additions are installed and other features like clipboard work. I create the share in the VB UI and it seems happy/sure enough that it created it. The mount point is never created nor shows up in 'df'. I have tried creating the shared folder from the menu within the VM and from the settings option in the VB control panel prior to starting. Lots of restarts, and shutdowns, to see if it would come back. Looked at lots of stuff online, but could not find anything to explain.